Display Stock on product widget
I am using magento 2.4.6 with martfury theme. I want to display stock level on product that's displayed via widget. Also, I have MSI enabled for the store.
I am using the below code to display the stock level, but it throws me error. can you please suggest how to do it. I am a beginner in magento.
$ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();     
     // $StockState = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');     
      echo $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()); 


